# How to add http in iframe source code before a link?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am using JSON(HTML Source) and contain iframe with source like

```
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/b34jsdg" height="360" width="640" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
```

I'm unable to add http before www.youtube.com/embed/b34jsdg the link and using this query.

```
    <script>$('iframe').each(function (){var a = 'https://'+$(this).attr('src');$(this).attr('src',a);});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that when you are using jQuery that you are waiting until the document is ready before altering it.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  // Your code here
});
```

Also, whenever a link comes back from the server prefixed with '//' such as in your iframe, then that content is loaded over whatever protocol the page was loaded over. So '//www.google.com' in an iframe loaded from **https**://somewebsite.com, that iframe will load it's content over **https** also. So the iframe will load **https**://www.google.com.